# ASP.NET Not sure if reading from SQL Server database correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to make a user register page that uploads the user data to a sql server database. I want to have the capability to check if a username already exists and prevent it from being made. I am able to create a new user with first name, last name, username, etc and it updates the database, but it doesn't stop me from creating a user with a username that already exists in the database. Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        //connect registration form to database
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sandboxConnectionStringUserData"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();    //open connection
        //SQL Query
        string checkUserName = "select count(*) from UserData where UserName='"+TextBoxUserName.Text+"'";//checks if username is already there
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(checkUserName, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if(temp == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("User name already exists");
        }
        conn.Close();   //close the database

    }
}
```

I tried debugging and temp's value never changes to 1.

Thanks!

Comment: You SHOULD NEVER DO THIS!@!!!!@!@!@!, never take the direct input of a submitted field and append it directly to a dynamic sql statement, I could EASILY delete your entire database with a very specific entry in that text box. NEVER DO THIS!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a UNIQUE constraint to the username column and handle the sql exception in your app. Additionally you can/should write an SP that takes username as an argument and checks for existence in the table, and use that in your server-side validation after the form is sorted but before the insert (save()) occurs.  That way you reduce the probability of encountering a sql exception but can still deal with it if it occurs.

Your current method of appending the form data to a raw sql query is going to open you up to sql injection. Use a parameterized query instead.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a [UNIQUE constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx) on the UserName column is a good start. I would also create a stored procedure that checks the existence of the user and inserts or updates as well structure your code a bit more efficiently. The username should be passed in as a parameter and you should properly dispose of the connection object.

As an example your stored procedure may look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspUserData @userName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.UserData WITH(NOLOCK)
          WHERE UserName = @userName)
    BEGIN
        -- update
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- insert
    END
END
```

And your .NET code may look like:

```
        using (
                SqlConnection conn =
                    new SqlConnection(
                        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sandboxConnectionStringUserData"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspUserData", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxUserName.Text;
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```